# travel distance needed to trigger significant location change update and accuracy of given location

Tags: ios, background, location, core-location

I've searched the SO on this topic and the newest result I could found was from march 2014 and iOS7. How are things regarding significant location changes standing now? I am interested in the accuracy of the location I get and more importantly, how much distance has to be travelled to get an update. Is 300m-400m travel distance in cities enough to trigger an update? What about 2km for more rural areas?

This question is related to [significant location change does not trigger on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35467603/significant-location-change-does-not-trigger-on-device)

Answer (score -1):

When the updates are triggered varies based on a combination of the distance between cell-towers and how often you configure the `CLLocationManager` to update (i.e Only get updates if I've travelled 1 mile), how accurate you need it and what type of navigation you are using it for.

There is no guarantee that you will get an update as often as you specify especially in more rural areas since iOS Optimises for battery.

Comment: Is it possible to configure when to get location updates if I am using significant location change? I was under impression that option is only for "standard location change" - continuous location updates.