# significant location change does not trigger on device

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager

I am using significant location change monitoring. When I run the code in the simulator and check Freeway option I get periodic location updates. I grab these updates and save them in NSUserDefaults and than update tableview every 10s, so I can see if I got any updates. If I run the app on a real device, I get zero updates. I kept the phone in my pocket and travelled over 80km, been in 2 cities. Zero updates. Not sure if I messed something up. I am attaching the code. The code is copy paste, feel free to test. Just make sure to use TableViewController in storyboard and set cell id to ID. What am I missing?  I am testing on iphone 5.

info.plist:

[image]

edit: Found this in apple docs. Should my `locationManager` be created differently?

> When an app is relaunched because of a location update, the launch
>   options dictionary passed to your
>   application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions: or
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method contains the
>   UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey key. The presence of that key
>   signals that new location data is waiting to be delivered to your app.
>   To obtain that data, you must create a new CLLocationManager object
>   and restart the location services that you had running prior to your
>   app’s termination. When you restart those services, the location
>   manager delivers all pending location updates to its delegate.

edit2:

Based on this, the location should be updated at least every 15min. Bug in my code confirmed.

> If GPS-level accuracy isn’t critical for your app and you don’t need
>   continuous tracking, you can use the significant-change location
>   service. It’s crucial that you use the significant-change location
>   service correctly, because it wakes the system and your app at least
>   every 15 minutes, even if no location changes have occurred, and it
>   runs continuously until you stop it.

edit3: added this code to AppDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` to see if app gets awaken. It does not get awaken-I see no 200 200 entry in table view. Something fishy is going on.

```
 if let options = launchOptions {
            print("options")
            if (launchOptions![UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey] != nil){
                locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
                self.lat.append(Double(200))
                self.lon.append(Double(200))
                self.times.append(NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(NSDate(), dateStyle: .NoStyle, timeStyle: .ShortStyle))
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(lat, forKey: "lat")
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(lon, forKey: "lon")
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(times, forKey: "time")
            }
```

CODE:
//AppDelegate:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var lat:[CLLocationDegrees]!
    var lon:[CLLocationDegrees]!
    var times:[String]!
    var distances: [String]!

    var window: UIWindow?
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        locationManager=CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate=self
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        let isFirstLaunch = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("lat")
        if isFirstLaunch == nil{
            lat = [CLLocationDegrees]()
            lon = [CLLocationDegrees]()
            times = [String]()
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(lat, forKey: "lat")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(lon, forKey: "lon")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(times, forKey: "time")
        }else{
            lat = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("lat") as! [CLLocationDegrees]
            lon = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("lon") as! [CLLocationDegrees]
            times = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("time") as! [String]
//            distances = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("distance") as! [String]

        }  
        return true
    }



    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        print("location updated")

        self.lat.append(locations[0].coordinate.latitude)
        self.lon.append(locations[0].coordinate.longitude)
        self.times.append(NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(NSDate(), dateStyle: .NoStyle, timeStyle: .ShortStyle))

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(lat, forKey: "lat")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(lon, forKey: "lon")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(times, forKey: "time")

        print("Location: \(locations[0].coordinate.latitude)   \(locations[0].coordinate.longitude)")
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        print("did change AS")
        switch status {
        case .AuthorizedWhenInUse:
            locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
        case .AuthorizedAlways:
            print("to always")
            locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
            if lat.count==0{
                self.lat.append((locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!)
                self.lon.append((locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!)

                self.times.append(NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(NSDate(), dateStyle: .NoStyle, timeStyle: .ShortStyle))

                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(lat, forKey: "lat")
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(lon, forKey: "lon")
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(times, forKey: "time")


            }

//            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            break
        default:
            locationManager.stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
            break
        }
    }
}
```

// View Controller

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let appDel = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10, target: self, selector: "updateTableView", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }



    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return appDel.lon.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ID", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(appDel.lat[indexPath.row])   \(appDel.lon[indexPath.row])    \(appDel.times[indexPath.row])"
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(9)


        return cell
    }

    func updateTableView(){
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you actually see the request for authorisation? If not, have you got NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in your plist?

Comment: yes the request pops out.  And yes, NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription  string is set in info.plist.

Comment: Are you killing the app by double tapping the home button and swiping up on the app? If you kill an app that way, it won't run background significant change services.

Comment: Yes, I am doing that. I think most of the users do that quiet often too. Is there a better to suspend an app?

Comment: No, that does not suspend an app, that kills it entirely and prevents further background interaction. Instead of killing the app, merely tap the home button once and go to another app, without killing the other one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are several problems with the code:

1. The location updates are not started when the app is launched by iOS.
2. Background location updates are not requested.
3. The code relies on changes in authorization status to start location updates
4. There is a missing break statement in the **didChangeAuthorizationStatus** method.

Here are the relevant documents:

- [startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges)
- [didChangeAuthorizationStatus](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:)
- [allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates)

The first document says a location manager object must be fully configured when iOS launches the app so the location event can be delivered to the app.

> Upon relaunch, you must still configure a location manager object and call this  method [startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges] to continue receiving location events.

This is how I usually do it to ensure that the location manager is fully started regardless of if it was launched from the icon or by iOS (sorry I use ObjectiveC).

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.

  NSLog(@"app launching");
  bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

  locationMgr = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
  [locationMgr setDelegate:self];
  if([locationMgr respondsToSelector:@selector(setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:)])
    [locationMgr setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:YES];
  CLAuthorizationStatus authorizationStatus= [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];

  if([launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey] != nil) {
    NSLog(@"relaunching because of significant location change - restarting SLC");
    [locationMgr startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
  }
  else
  {
    if (authorizationStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways) {
        NSLog(@"launching with authorization to always use location - starting SLC");
        [locationMgr startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"launching with no authorization to always use location - requesting authorization");
        if([locationMgr respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)])
            [locationMgr requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
  }

  return YES;
}
```

Notice the call to **setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates**. This is new in iOS9 and must be done everytime the app starts if you want to receive locations updates in the background. (It is like a "I'm not kidding, I know I asked for them in the background modes, but I really do want them").

> Apps that want to receive location updates when suspended must include the UIBackgroundModes key (with the location value) in their app’s Info.plist file and set the value of this property to YES.

Finally you can't rely on **didChangeAuthorizationStatus** being called. If you have the authorization *kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways* then calling **[locationMgr requestAlwaysAuthorization]** doesn't result in a change in authorization status, so **didChangeAuthorizationStatus** isn't called.

> If the authorization status is already known when you call the requestWhenInUseAuthorization or requestAlwaysAuthorization method, the location manager does not report the current authorization status to this method.

Comment: No problem - Apple have steadily made CoreLocation more difficult to use correctly with every release of iOS. I think it was perfect around iOS6, now it's just arcane. Good luck with your project.

Comment: Can't argue with that. On a side note. I've been playing around now for a couple of days. Apple advertises that significant location will be triggered at least each 15min, regardless of actual location change. I am not getting  any updates if I am not moving. Are you seeing location updates in your apps every 15min, even if you are not moving?

Comment: I have only seen it trigger on cell change, remove the sim card and you will never get woken up. I think the 15 mins refers to the fact that a phone doesn't lock onto a single cell and stay there, it can wander from cell to cell because mobile cellular networks operate in a fading RF environment. This means a signal that was strong previously may become weaker over time. The rate at which the phone changes towers depends on the rate of RF fade and the power difference threshold parameter used on the adjacent cells.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to startUpdatingLocation regardless? Have you tried inserting breakpoints to see where you get to?

Comment: if i set the startUpdatingLocation to true I get 3 updates per second. I think it is only meany for standard location services. I haven't, because it works great on a simulator.

Comment: Is it possible to use breakpoints on a suspended app in background?

Comment: @krompir2 - No, you can't use breakpoints in this case. I generally `NSLog` messages (so I can watch the console). I have also found it useful to log the messages to some persistent storage and then when I bring the app to foreground, show these saved messages in a table view or something like that, so I can diagnose what took place while the app was not in foreground.

Comment: You can set a break point on a process that is suspended or not even running.

Comment: If the process is suspended, in Xcode click on the Debug menu and select "Attach to Process" - select your process. You are now attached and when the process runs, if it hits a breakpoint it will stop. If the process is not running, in Xcode click on the Debug menu and select "Attach to Process by PID or Name...". Enter the name of your process. click Attach. The debugger will attach to you process when it launches because of an SLC.